# Width table column bootstrap 3.3 with button

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I got the following table with a "view" button in a template.php. Im using bootstrap 3.3.7

```
<?php

if($num>0){

    echo "<table class='table table-responsive table-sm table-hover table-bordered'>";

    echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Name</th>";
            echo "<th>Description</th>";
            echo "<th></th>";
        echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";    

    echo "<tbody>";

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

            extract($row);

            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>{$name}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$description}</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                    echo "<a href='view_thing.php?id={$id}' class='btn-info btn-sm'>";
                        echo "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span> View";
                    echo "</a>";
                echo "</td>";

            echo "</tr>";

        }
echo "</tbody>";        
    echo "</table>";

    ?>
```

It looks like:
[table test 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2YDc.png)

**What i tried:**

```
    <th class="col-md-1"></th>
    <th style="width: 10%"></th>
```

**What it should do:**

The last column should fit the button size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
echo <th style=width: '10%'></th>
```